# SharpScript .ss file works to connect to database, but same code doesn't work when served to local web-browser?

Tags: servicestack, csharpscript

I have a SharpScript .ss script file with some small code that polls a database and formats things to display. The output is getting too unruly for command line output so I wanted to generate html and view things like that. Generating the html works fine with htmlDump in the .ss file, but when I create a small web project from one of their templates, the database connection stops working?

**Is there any difference in how to specify the connection string for a website vs. a .ss script file?**

I just have the regular args specification at the beginning of the file

```
<!--
db mssql
db.connection Server=ble\bla;Database=blu;user id=blo;password=#blingblong#
-->
```

This works fine in .ss script file, I can then do something like

````
```code
{{ 
    "select * from View drv
        join [Project] p on drv.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
        where DocumentId = 'GUID' " 
    | dbSelect
    | map => {it.RecordId, it.Text, it.Name}
    | to => sqlMap 
}}

sqlMap | count
sqlMap | textDump
```
````

and get output like the count (21) and a table from the textDump.

I then created a "bare-webapp" from a template with `web new bare-webapp Name` and added a new html file with the same content, but that doesn't work? If I do

```
{{dbTableNames | count }}

{{db}}
```

I can see that the db argument is rendered in the browser as "mssql" like in the argument input, but the table names are not listed, and no sql queries work. I don't see any error messages or anything, so I have no idea what is going on? I thought SharpScript would be able to render the html page similarly to how .ss script files can access the database?

Comment: If I try to access the "connection" property of the "db" argument, I get an error, but I just think that's because I don't know the correct syntax. If I do `{{db.connection}}` I get error about `'String' does not have a 'connection' property or field` - I get the same error when trying that in the .ss script file.

Comment: I was running this against a remote SQL server, but also tried running against a local SQL server, and same thing, works in .ss file but not when served to html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are very different contexts. The [stand-alone .ss Sharp Scripts](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-scripts) are executed within the context of a [Sharp App](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps) that's executed by the [dotnet tools](https://docs.servicestack.net/dotnet-tool) which have access to all ServiceStack implementation assemblies. So when the script sees:

```
<!--
db mssql
db.connection Server=ble\bla;Database=blu;user id=blo;password=#blingblong#
-->
```

It creates a `ScriptContext` pre-configured with [#Script Database Scripts](https://sharpscript.net/docs/db-scripts) and an `OrmLiteConnectionFactory` configured with the [ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/ServiceStack.OrmLite.SqlServer) Provider and your connection string.

By contrast [#Script Pages](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-pages) executing in a web page only has access to the `SharpPagesFeature` context that's configured in your App. So you'll need to configure OrmLite in your AppHost as normal, e.g:

```
container.AddSingleton<IDbConnectionFactory>(() => 
    new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServer2012Dialect.Provider));
```

Then make the [Database Scripts](https://sharpscript.net/docs/db-scripts) available to your `SharpPagesFeature`, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new SharpPagesFeature {
    ScriptMethods = {
        new DbScriptsAsync()
    }
});
```

Which will give your pages access to the Database Scripts which will use your registered `OrmLiteConnectionFactory`.

### [Sharp Apps](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps)

Sharp Apps are a way to rapidly develop Web Apps created entirely using `#Script` which enables an instant feedback live development model as your App doesn't require re-compilation or restarts. Sharp Apps, just like your Sharp Scripts are both run

```
$ x new bare-webapp ProjectName
```

Then you can start your Sharp App with `x run` in your App's directory, e.g:

```
$ cd ProjectName
$ x run
```

The same functionality in [Sharp Scripts](https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-scripts) is also available to Sharp Apps, but instead of adding your App configuration to the top of your script you'd instead add it to your `app.settings`, e.g:

```
db mssql
db.connection Server=ble\bla;Database=blu;user id=blo;password=#blingblong#
```

---

Please note from v5.7 #Script is [transitioning to use the JS Pipeline Operator Syntax](https://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.7#transition-to-js-pipeline-operator-syntax), so it's now recommended to write:

````
```code
{{ 
    "select * from View drv
        join [Project] p on drv.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
        where DocumentId = 'GUID' " 
    |> dbSelect
    |> map => {it.RecordId, it.Text, it.Name}
    |> to => sqlMap 
}}

sqlMap |> count
sqlMap |> textDump
```
````

Comment: Ok, thanks for the great info. But when I create `web new bare-webapp wata` I don't see any way to add C# code, all the files are just html files? Is it not possible to configure in the bare-webapp? What template should I be using? I really like the way to run the bare-webapp with just `web` in the base folder, so I'd like to be able to do that still, if possible.

Comment: @gakera ‘webapp’ are Sharp App Templates, create a new ‘script’ project to create a new website configured with #Script Pages

Comment: ok thanks. Is it correct understanding that Sharp Apps can't be configured to talk to a database?

Comment: @gakera What made you think that? Your Sharp Script is a Sharp App which connects to a DB and there are a number of Sharp App examples that use DB Scripts https://sharpscript.net/docs/sharp-apps

Comment: So it's just the `bare-webapp` that can't be configured to connect to a DB? Ok that makes more sense, I guess it's very "bare" haha

Comment: It’s a Sharp App so it can be configured like any Sharp App where app configuration is maintained in app.settings, please read the Sharp App docs I linked to there’s ample docs and examples that use DB Scripts

Comment: ok, great then that is what I want to do, to configure the bare Sharp App to talk to the database using app.settings. It seems I can just add the `db mssql
db.connection Server=ble\bla;Database=blu;user id=blo;password=#blingblong#` stuff to app.settings and everything works!

Comment: @gakera Right because the page variables at the top of your stand-alone Sharp Script is an alternative available to Sharp Scripts instead of specifying them in your `app.settings`, I've updated my question to mention Sharp Apps,